# How to change font-size of text in bootstrap-toggle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

That's pretty much the question. I have a bootstrap toggle button. I want to increase the size of the text (the data-on attribute and data-off attribute)

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-style="android" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="info" data-on="increaseSize" data-off="increaseSize" data-width="500" data-height="200" data-size="large">
```

Heres what it looks like on the phone.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you want to increase the size of the text when those variables change? Or when the checkbox is clicked...or something else?

Comment: Please create a fiddle and share it with us.

Comment: it's on the phone, I'm creating a mobile webpage, the text on the buttons is very small, too small to see, I just want to increase their size, that's it, not when those variables change or when the checkbox is clicked but in general

Comment: @Rockstar5645 The above code alone is not responsible to display what you are showing on the image. Please share more code.

Answer (score 0):

@Rockstar5645
simply by using CSS:

```
.toggle.android .toggle-group label {

    font-size: 20px;
}
```

html (as posted, no change):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-style="android" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="info" data-on="increaseSize" data-off="increaseSize" data-width="500" data-height="200" data-size="large">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="outline-secondary" data-on="on" data-off="off" >
```

```css
.toggle, .toggle-on, .toggle-off{
  font-size: 13px;    // set font-size for on-off state
}
.toggle.btn{
  height:30px !important;    // set height for btn
}
```